# How to navigate to a screen using useNavigation() in react native with typescript

Tags: typescript, react-hooks, react-native, react-native-navigation

I wanted to use `useNavigation` to navigate to a screen.
Below is my code:

MainNav.tsx:

```
const defaultNavigationOptions: StackNavigationOptions = {
    ...
    ...
    ...
    headerRight: (props) => {
        return <AccountHeaderComponent tintColor={props.tintColor} />;
    },
    ...
    ...
    ...
};


const MainNavigator = () => {
return (
        <MainStack.Navigator>
            <MainStack.Screen
                name={"VerificationScreen}
                component={VerificationScreen}
            />
        </MainStack.Navigator>
    );
};
```

This created a header with a profile icon like in below image.

when clicked on it, it will go to component `AccountHeaderComponent`

[image]

AccountHeaderComponent.tsx:

```
import AccountsPopUpComponent from "./AccountsPopUpComponent";

export interface AccountHeaderComponentProps {
    tintColor?: string,}

const AccountHeaderComponent = (props: AccountHeaderComponentProps) => {
    const {tintColor} = props;}
    return (<>
          <Modal>
              <AccountsPopUpComponent/>
          </Modal>
          <TouchableOpacity>
              <View>
                  <Icon name={'account-outline'}/>
              </View>
          </TouchableOpacity>
      </>
        </>
    )
};
```

Notice that Here I am having a component called `AccountsPopUpComponent`

AccountsPopUpComponent.tsx:

```
const AccountsPopUpComponent = (props: any) => {
    const {onClose} = props;

    const getCurrentPage = () => {
        switch (page) {
            case '':
                return <ProfileComponent />
            default:
                return <DummyComponent/>
        }
    }

    return (
          <View style={{flex: 1}}>{getCurrentPage()}</View>
    )
};
```

Finally I have a `ProfileComponent` from which I want to navigate to `VerificationScreen`, which is in the main navigator.

ProfileComponent.tsx:

```
const ProfileComponent = (props: ProfileComponentProps) => {
  const navigation = useNavigation();

  const gotoVerifyScreen= () => {
    navigation.navigate(VerificationScreen);
  };

  return (
    <>
          <VerifyRibbonComponent
            gotoOTP={gotoVerifyScreen}
          />
    </>
  );
};
```

here in `gotoVerifyScreen` I have used `useNavigation` to go to verify screen, it doesn't take me to that screen, but if I click back button of my device then I can see that screen. This is not the kind of functionality which I wanted. I want to see that screen when I click on `VerifyRibbonComponent`. I have tried very hard, but unable to find the mistake which I am doing

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a component in the header of a navigation stack, you should use the navigation from props instead of useNavigation (I can't find the documentation about it).

Try to replace `const navigation = useNavigation();` with `const navigation = props.navigation;`

```
const defaultNavigationOptions: StackNavigationOptions = {
    ...
    ...
    ...
    headerRight: (props) => {
        return <AccountHeaderComponent 
           {...props} // <--- ADD THIS
           tintColor={props.tintColor} />;
    },
    ...
    ...
    ...
};
```

```
const AccountHeaderComponent = (props: AccountHeaderComponentProps) => {
    const {tintColor} = props;}
    return (<>
          <Modal>
              <AccountsPopUpComponent 
                {...props} // <--- ADD THIS
              />
          </Modal>
          <TouchableOpacity>
              <View>
                  <Icon name={'account-outline'}/>
              </View>
          </TouchableOpacity>
      </>
        </>
    )
};
```

```
const AccountsPopUpComponent = (props: any) => {
    const {onClose} = props;

    const getCurrentPage = () => {
        switch (page) {
            case '':
                return <ProfileComponent {...props} /> // <--- ADD THIS
            default:
                return <DummyComponent {...props} /> // <--- ADD THIS
        }
    }

    return (
          <View style={{flex: 1}}>{getCurrentPage()}</View>
    )
};
```

```
const ProfileComponent = (props: ProfileComponentProps) => {
  const gotoVerifyScreen= () => {
    props.navigation.navigate(VerificationScreen); // <--- CHANGE HERE
  };

  return (
    <>
          <VerifyRibbonComponent
            gotoOTP={gotoVerifyScreen}
          />
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: for this I have to pass navigation as props through all the components, which I don't want to do

Comment: It's only for the components on navigation header. useNavigation will work for every other component

Comment: its not working `Property 'navigation' does not exist on type 'ProfileComponentProps'.`

Comment: I updated the answer. You weren't passing the original props from react-navigation